# org.json unable to convert json to xml properly- json object with nested objects and arrays.Need alternate approach

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

I have a requirement to convert json to xml.

I am using org.json jar file

However, the order of  elements in xml is different and also few elements are missing while conversin. The input message is a nested json object with json arrays.
For simple json to xml, the code works fine. 
Please provide an alternate approach/ library for this problem

```
package jjson;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
public class Json {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    InputStreamReader is = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    try {

        File jsonFile = new File("<<provide location of file>>");
        is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonFile), "UTF-8");

        // Read the input stream and covert into string object
        //is = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();

        while (read != null) {
            // System.out.println(read);
            sb.append(read);
            read = br.readLine();

        }

        // Convert the String object to XML and write in the default name

        String xml = XML.toString(new JSONObject(sb.toString()));
        System.out.println(xml);
        //String service.write(xml.getBytes(), "default");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    } finally {

        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edit :

Input message

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Recipient": "xyz.ang@abcd.com",
"RequestedComments": null,
"GeneratedAutomatically": false,
"From": "Africa",
"To": "China",
"ResponsesPage": {
"Tables": [
  {
    "Name": null,
    "Columns": [
      "Question",
      "Response"
    ],
    "Rows": [
      {
        "Name": "1. General",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "1. General",
            "Name": "SECTION_GENERAL",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": null,
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 5
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "1.1 Name of completing party",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "1.1 Name of completing party",
            "Name": "COMPLETING_PARTY",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": "Captain",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 0
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "1.2 Relationship",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "1.2 Relationship",
            "Name": "RELATIONSHIP",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": "Owner",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 1
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "2. Details",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2. Details",
            "Name": "SECTION_DETAILS",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": null,
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 5
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "2.1 FlatNumber",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2.1 IMO Number",
            "Name": "IMP_NUMBER",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": "9336012",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 2
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      }
    ]
   },
   {
    "Name": "IDENTIFIER_GRID",
    "Columns": [
      "Question",
      "Data",
      "Correction if required"
    ],
    "Rows": [
      {
        "Name": "2.2 Name",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2.2 Name",
            "Name": "TEXT_QUESTION",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Data",
            "Value": "IVS CABERNET",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 0
          },
          {
            "Key": "2.2 Name",
            "Value": "",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": null
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "2.3",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2.3",
            "Name": "TEXT_QUESTION",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Data",
            "Value": "565598000",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 0
          },
          {
            "Key": "2.3 Maritime Mobile",
            "Value": "",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": null
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "2.4 Build Date",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2.4 Build Date",
            "Name": "TEXT_QUESTION",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "RightShip Data",
            "Value": "01 Oct 2007",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 0
          },
          {
            "Key": "2.4 Build Date",
            "Value": "04 Oct. 2007",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": null
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": null,
     "Columns": [
      "Question",
      "Response"
     ],
     "Rows": [
      {
        "Name": "2.5 Vessel Type ",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "2.5 Vessel Type ",
            "Name": "SHIP_TYPE",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": "Bulk Carrier",
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 1
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      }
     ]
   },
   {
    "Name": "VESSEL_DETAILS_GRID",
    "Columns": [
      "Question",
      "Data",
      "Correction if required"
     ],
       "Rows": [
      {
        "Name": "10. Attachments",
        "Columns": [
          {
            "Key": "Question",
            "Value": "10. Attachments",
            "Name": "SECTION_ATTACHMENTS",
            "Type": null
          },
          {
            "Key": "Response",
            "Value": null,
            "Name": null,
            "Type": 5
          }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
        "ValidationMessage": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
"QuestionsCount": 147,
"RulesCount": 5,
"PassedCount": 5,
"RequiredCount": 0,
"FCount": 0,
"VId": 190980,
"AId": null,
"AssignedTo": null,
"AssignedToName": null,
"AssignedToCustomer": null,
"AssignedOn": null,
"DecidedBy": "ABC",
"DecidedByName": "Red",
"DecidedByCustomerCode": "CSMC",
"DecidedByCustomerName": "CSG",
"DecidedOn": "2017-05-02T15:14:18.893Z",
"DecidedComments": "Acceptable",
"DecidedAutomatically": false,
"Vessel": {
 "Id": 190980,
 "IMP": 1234,
 "PrId": "12345",
 "Name": "IVS CABERNET",
 "Ttatus": "In Service/Commission",
 "VesselType": "Bulk Carrier",
 "DWT": 177173,
 "Age": 9.5,
 "ActivityConfigList": null,
 "Links": []
 },
 "Attachments": [],
 "History": null,
 "Comments": null,
 "Reports": [],
 "Links": []
 }
```

Expected output XML: (for sample added JSON as  root element)

```
<JSON>
<Id>1</Id>
<Recipient>xyz.ang@abcd.com</Recipient>
<RequestedComments/>
<GeneratedAutomatically>false</GeneratedAutomatically>
<From>Africa</From>
<To>China</To>
<ResponsesPage>
    <Tables>
        <Name/>
        <Columns>Question</Columns>
        <Columns>Response</Columns>
        <Rows>
            <Name>1. General</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>1. General</Value>
                <Name>SECTION_GENERAL</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value/>
                <Name/>
                <Type>5</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>1.1 Name of completing party</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>1.1 Name of completing party</Value>
                <Name>COMPLETING_PARTY</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value>Captain</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>0</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>1.2 Relationship</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>1.2 Relationship</Value>
                <Name>RELATIONSHIP</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value>Owner</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>1</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2. Details</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2. Details</Value>
                <Name>SECTION_DETAILS</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value/>
                <Name/>
                <Type>5</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2.1 FlatNumber</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2.1 IMO Number</Value>
                <Name>IMP_NUMBER</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value>9336012</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>2</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
    </Tables>
    <Tables>
        <Name>IDENTIFIER_GRID</Name>
        <Columns>Question</Columns>
        <Columns>Data</Columns>
        <Columns>Correction if required</Columns>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2.2 Name</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2.2 Name</Value>
                <Name>TEXT_QUESTION</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Data</Key>
                <Value>IVS CABERNET</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>0</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>2.2 Name</Key>
                <Value/>
                <Name/>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2.3</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2.3</Value>
                <Name>TEXT_QUESTION</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Data</Key>
                <Value>565598000</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>0</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>2.3 Maritime Mobile</Key>
                <Value/>
                <Name/>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2.4 Build Date</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2.4 Build Date</Value>
                <Name>TEXT_QUESTION</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>RightShip Data</Key>
                <Value>01 Oct 2007</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>0</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>2.4 Build Date</Key>
                <Value>04 Oct. 2007</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
    </Tables>
    <Tables>
        <Name/>
        <Columns>Question</Columns>
        <Columns>Response</Columns>
        <Rows>
            <Name>2.5 Vessel Type </Name>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Question</Key>
                <Value>2.5 Vessel Type </Value>
                <Name>SHIP_TYPE</Name>
                <Type/>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <Key>Response</Key>
                <Value>Bulk Carrier</Value>
                <Name/>
                <Type>1</Type>
            </Columns>
            <Status>0</Status>
            <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
    </Tables>
    <Tables>
        <Name>VESSEL_DETAILS_GRID</Name>
        <Columns>Question</Columns>
        <Columns>RightShip Data</Columns>
        <Columns>Correction if required</Columns>
        <Rows>
           <Name>10. Attachments</Name>
           <Columns>
            <Key>Question</Key>
            <Value>10. Attachments</Value>
            <Name>SECTION_ATTACHMENTS</Name>
            <Type/>
          </Columns>
          <Columns>
          <Key>Response</Key>
           <Value/>
           <Name/>
           <Type>5</Type>
           </Columns>
           <Status>0</Status>
          <ValidationMessage/>
        </Rows>
    </Tables>
 </ResponsesPage>
 <QuestionsCount>147</QuestionsCount>
 <RulesCount>5</RulesCount>
 <PassedCount>5</PassedCount>
 <RequiredCount>0</RequiredCount>
 <FCount>0</FCount>
 <VId>190980</VId>
 <AId/>
 <AssignedTo/>
 <AssignedToName/>
 <AssignedToCustomer/>
 <AssignedOn/>
 <DecidedBy>ABC</DecidedBy>
 <DecidedByName>Red</DecidedByName>
 <DecidedByCustomerCode>CSMC</DecidedByCustomerCode>
 <DecidedByCustomerName>CSG</DecidedByCustomerName>
 <DecidedOn>2017-05-02T15:14:18.893Z</DecidedOn>
 <DecidedComments>Acceptable</DecidedComments>
 <DecidedAutomatically>false</DecidedAutomatically>
  <Vessel>
    <Id>190980</Id>
    <IMP>1234</IMP>
    <PrId>12345</PrId>
    <Name>IVS CABERNET</Name>
    <Ttatus>In Service/Commission</Ttatus>
    <VesselType>Bulk Carrier</VesselType>
    <DWT>177173</DWT>
    <Age>9.5</Age>
    <ActivityConfigList/>
    <Links/>
 </Vessel>
 <Attachments/>
 <History/>
 <Comments/>
 <Reports/>
 <Links/>
 </JSON>
```

Thanks,
Krish

Comment: Please tell us what the input JSON looks like, what you want the target XML to look like, and what your current approach generates. Telling us "this doesn't work, can you suggest something else" is not an adequate statement of your requirements.

Comment: Hi, i have added the target xml, and input json. They were pretty big originally and hence i did not add them to the post. I have added them now by editing the message's content. My current output has few tags missing and in some placed not in the right order.

Comment: In a JSON "object", the order of entries is not normally considered significant (in many languages it will appear as a map, hash, or dictionary, which is essentially unordered). So a requirement to retain order may be tricky to satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet gives the output you are looking for (it does a generic conversion to XML using the json-to-xml() function, and then transforms the generic XML to the specific form you require):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <JSON>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text('test.json'))"/>
        </JSON>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key[. castable as xs:NCName]]" priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="{@key}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@key[not(. castable as xs:NCName)]]" priority="2">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">Key {@key} cannot be used as an element name</xsl:message>    
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key[. castable as xs:NCName]][exists(*)]" priority="3">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="{../@key}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key[. castable as xs:NCName]][empty(*)]" priority="3">
        <xsl:element name="{@key}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, what i am looking for is an approach on how json is converted to xml. Org.json read the file line by line and converted that to a jsonobject and then the jsonobject is converted to xml string.

Comment: I will add some more context around the problem.

1.In my case json response is from a third party. 
2.Org.json - code i used, read the file line by line and converted that to a jsonobject and then the jsonobject is converted to xml string.
3. On the other hand, the sample output i gave is from a tool which has the potential to convert json to xml . 
4.So, this xslt is based on the xml output right, and if my json response changes for instance, will the xslt is still applicable or will i be facing any changes. 
Thanks heaps.

Comment: The XSLT implements rules which I inferred from your example. If your JSON changes, for example if it uses key values that are not valid as XML element names, then the stylesheet will need to change. There is no general way of converting JSON to XML that meets all requirements: that's why an XSLT approach is useful, because it gives you the flexibility to define the rules yourself.

Comment: Hi Michael, Am trying to implement this in java, looking up on internet since i never worked on similar stuff. Do we need any supporting jars?
Also, can SAXON-B XSLT 2.0 be used here ? 
Also, during the json to xml conversion will the data  or elements be lost, the same way it happened in org.json to string conversion?

Comment: Saxon implements XSLT 3.0 currently only in the commercial editions - you can run this with Saxon-PE 9.7 (get a 30-day evaluation license). Support for XSLT 3.0 will move into the open-source Saxon-HE product when 3.0 becomes a Recommendation, hopefully very soon.

Comment: Basically, the JSON-to-XML and XML-to-JSON support in XSLT 3.0 is much more under user control than you get with the json.org or jackson libraries, which you would expect because XSLT is a language for defining transformations. So you can select which parts to include in the output and how to represent them by writing appropriate template rules. In answer to the other question, this is all new in XSLT 3.0.